# Как использовать aria-labellbdy?

Tags: html5

Растолкуйте, пожалуйста, кто чем может)
1. aria используются для того, чтобы пояснить через экранную читалку, например, пользователю, что именно здесь находится.
Я читал документацию и понял, что просто нужно указать некий текст, который машина просто прочтет, чтобы пользователю было понятно, что есть ху. И, как я понимаю, aria-label используется там, где нет никакого контента, а aria-labelledby - напротив, там, где контент есть. Это так?

2. Валидатор ругается, говорит так: 
   The aria-labelledby attribute must point to an element in the same document.
   А, как именно атрибут должен указывать на элемент в том же документе? 
   Почему нельзя сделать так:

```html
<span class="comments-informer" aria-labelledby="Количество комментариев" id="item1">36</span>
```

?
Благодарю!

Comment: `aria-labelledby` в нём вы должны указать `id` элемента формы. Например input и прочее. А `aria-label` указывается текст. если визуально сразу не понять для чего нужно, например `<button aria-label="Закрыть">X</button>`

Answer (score 0):

О, все, спасибо, я разобрался!

```html
<div id="billing">Billing</div>

<div>
    <div id="name">Name</div>
    <input type="text" aria-labelledby="billing name"/>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="address">Address</div>
    <input type="text" aria-labelledby="billing address"/>
</div>
```

Comment: На id какого-то элемента он ссылается просто добавлением его к самому описанию, там же внутри кавычек!)